# JQuery Mobile and HTML5 Video Tag

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, video

I'm working on a video sharing mobile website centered on step by step tutorials. I'm using JQuery Mobile and trying to embed videos using the html5  tag. However, it doesn't seem to work. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Can you show some snippets of code related to the issue? Maybe the tag is malformed, or it's missing a property. With code, we can better diagnose what the issue could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should have a HTML tag as below

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But some older Android browsers seem to mess up with it. So remove the `type` tag and embed into your html file and check. Something as below.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" >
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```